# Telerik Grid paging and Sorting in ASP.Net MVC3(aspx engine)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik Rad Grid in MVC3(aspx engine) like:-

**This is my Controller:-**

```
[HttpGet]
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
public ActionResult Search()
{
    SearchViewModel searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel(this.serviceInvoker);
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchViewModel.Initialize();
    ViewData["TotalRecord"] = SearchViewModel.SearchResponses.Count();
    return View(searchViewModel);
}
```

**This is my ViewModel:-**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("CaseSearch", "AdvanceSearch", FormMethod.Post, new { @class "formStyle" }))
   { %>
   <div class="boxPanel">
 <fieldset>
<legend></legend>
 <ul class="floatleft width25" >

         <div class="floatleft">                        
             <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewCaseSearch"); %>                
         </div>
  </fieldset>    
<% } %>
```

**This is my Partial View Telerik Grid:-**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="ABC.DataContracts.Messages" %>

<%= Html.Telerik().Grid((IEnumerable<SearchResponse>)Model.SearchResponses)
           .Name("CaseSearchGrid")

          .Columns(columns =>
               {                   
                   columns.Bound(grid => grid.RowNumber);
                   columns.Bound(grid => grid.CreatedOn).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
                   columns.Bound(grid => grid.CaseReference);
               })

               .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("Search", "AdvanceSearch"))
               .EnableCustomBinding(true)
               .BindTo((IEnumerable<SearchResponse>)Model.SearchResponses)
               .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(true))
%>
```

**SearchResponse**  is my object which is result of search request.

I have to implement Custom Server Ajax binding with Server side Paging ans Sorting. I have implemented Paging and sorting in my stored procedure. but when ever i am clicking on page index or sorting column its not returning proper data and throughing error like. " Invalid JSON request".

Please also assist me how to pass the sort column name and page index to my controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AdvanceSearch()` action should take `GridCommand` as it's parameter, so you know what sorting to apply. Take a look at Telerik documentation.

You can also attack the debugger in order to see what the actual exception on the server is.